# Datetime picker and modal conflict angular ui bootstrap

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have a problem, in one form, I have to create an angular pop up form so I use this tutorial [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and it worked well however my other field which is the date time picker got affected.

this is my code where I use modal:

```
<script src="{% static "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js" %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

      $scope.delivery={
        linktext: "{{form.delivery.value}}",
        hyperlink: "{{form.delivery.value}}"
            };

      $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

      $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'taskDelivery',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: 'sm',
          resolve: {
            linktext: function () {
              return $scope.linktext;
            },hyperlink: function () {
              return $scope.hyperlink;
            }
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (delivery) {
          $scope.delivery= {
             linktext: delivery.linktext,
             hyperlink: delivery.hyperlink
             };

        });
      };

      $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
        $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
      };

    });


    angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

      $scope.delivery = {
        linktext: "{{form.delivery.value}}",
        hyperlink: "{{form.delivery.value}}"
      };

      $scope.ok = function () {
          $modalInstance.close({
            linktext:$scope.delivery.linktext,
            hyperlink:$scope.delivery.hyperlink
            });
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
    });
</script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="taskDelivery">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Insert Link Here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Link Text: <input type="text" ng-model="delivery.linktext"> <br>
        Hyper Link: <input type="text" ng-model="delivery.hyperlink">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn-cancel" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn-save" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>


<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <div class="profileform">
        <div class="profile-detail">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                <div class="errormessage">
                    {% if field.errors %}
                    {{ field.errors }}<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <input type="text" value="{$ delivery.linktext $}" name="{{field.name}}" style="width:100px;" disabled>

                <input type="hidden" value="{$ delivery.linktext $}" name="{{field.name}}" style="width:100px;">
                <input type="text" value="{$ delivery.hyperlink $}" name="linknathis" style="width:200px;" disabled>
                <button type="button" ng-click="open()">Set Delivery</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is already working.. but my datetimepicker does not work but it does if I delete  `<script src="{% static "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js" %}"></script>`

This is my datetimepicker script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('DateTimepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}', function($scope) {
            // Set Javascript's Date Object value
            $scope.selectedDateTime = new Date('{{field.value|date:"Y/m/d H:i:s"}}');
    });
</script>

<div class="profileform" ng-controller="DateTimepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}">
    <div class="profile-detail">
    <div class="errormessage" style="margin-top:-10px;">
        {% if field.errors %}
        {{ field.errors }}<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>

        <!--Hidden field for transfer date & time-->
        <input type ="hidden"
            id="{{field.id_for_label}}"
            name="{{field.html_name}}"
            value="{$selectedDateTime|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'$}">
        <!--Field for select date-->
        <input style="width: 100px; padding-left: 5px;"
            type="text"
            ng-model="selectedDateTime"
            data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
            data-autoclose="1"
            bs-datepicker>
        <!--Field for select time-->
        <input style="width: 100px; padding-left: 5px;"
            type="text"
            ng-model="selectedDateTime"
            data-time-format="HH:mm"
            data-autoclose="1"
            data-length="1"
            bs-timepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you think I am having conflicts here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap-additions-0.3.1/bootstrap-additions.min.css" %}">
<script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "angularjs-1.4.3/angular-sanitize.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "angular-strap-2.3.1-dist/angular-strap.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "angular-strap-2.3.1-dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.3.js" %}"></script>

<script src="{% static "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly you are trying to use two different versions of UI-bootstrap, right?

Comment: Can you specify, what exactly is not working, do you get error messages, etc?

Comment: @fodma1, yes you are right

Comment: @schacki, only one of them can work if I delete the other. but I needed both of them.

Comment: btw I'm not sure about the dynamic controller naming `angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('DateTimepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}', function($scope) {` where does that field variable coma from? Otherwise you should use only the latest version from you library. You can use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker

Comment: I have edited my question and added all the libraries that might have caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems with your approach:

1. Using the multiple versions of a library will not work if it uses the same namespacing, which is the case. So either check, if the date-picker works with the latest ui-boostrap version es well. Or downgrade your code to the ui-bootstrap version that is required by the datepicker.
2. I might be wrong, but angular.module('actinbox.web').controller('DateTimepicker_{{ field.id_for_label }}' will b executed after angular bootstrap. Since angular, by default, does not support the lazy loading of modules. I do not think this will work. Try to test it by adding a console.log output to the controller and see if it ever works.

Comment: I have edited my question and added all the libraries that might have caused the problem